# Distinct in LINQ and change result type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get a list of distinct items from a database. 
I want the result to be in a list of CarMakes, which has only one property called Make.

I can get the following items to work in LINQPad, but when I try to get it working in C#.  I get the following error

"  *.First()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable()*,"

```
var result = await _context.Cars
              .GroupBy(x => x.Make)
              .Select(x =>   x.First().Make  )
              .ToListAsync();
```

I have tried the following, which can all the makes, but its not distinct.

```
var result = await _context.Cars
                .Select(x => new CarMakes() { Assembly =  x.Assembly })
                .ToListAsync();
```

The Car table has the following columns,  Id, Colour, Make, Model, Registration

I tried using MORELinq but couldnt get that working to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = await _context.Cars.Select(c => c.Make).Distinct()
                .Select(m => new CarMakes { Assembly = m })
                .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I didn't know distinct was in Linq, I can remember (years ago) it wasn't and had to user morelinq extension, or do the fun grouping thing.  Good to learn it's in,  I seem to have this question once a year.

Comment: @AshleyKilgour Good to hear that it helped ;)

Answer (score 1):

Could you try running the code below:

```
var result = await _context.Cars
              .GroupBy(x => x.Make)
              .Select(x =>   x.Key  )
              .ToListAsync();
```

Hope it helps! :)